# Sendgrid/python - json could not be unmarshalled

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

This python3 code returns an error:

```
import json
import requests

# Perform a Single Send 

headers = {
    "authorization": "Bearer <my-API-key>",
    "content-type": "application/json"
}

data = {
    "name": "Test Blast",
    "send_to": {
        "segment_ids": ["<a-segment-id>"],
        "all": False
    },
    "email_config": {
        "subject": "Test Blast",
        "html_content": "<h1>My Message</h1><p>Is a very simple one.</p>",
        "generate_plain_content": True
    }
}

url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/singlesends"
res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
print((res.status_code, res.text))
```

and the response is

```
(400, '{"errors":[{"field":"name","message":"cannot be empty string"}]}')
```

which isn't overly informative.  Running the same data (with the python booleans changed to true/false) with the 'Try it out' interface on https://sendgrid.com/docs/api-reference/
gives the error response of

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "",
            "message": "json could not be unmarshalled"
        }
    ]
```

Any clues to what is wrong, or what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is issue in this line :

```
res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

You are passing the empty payload variable in the request. You had assigned the json to data variable and passing payload.

So you need to change the variable payload to data in this line.After that it will works.

```
res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: If you found answer is helpful ,please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Was rushing to get that code running. :-)